# How to Pause & Resume Boost deadline timer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Is possible to make a deadline timer stop and restart ?

I'm developing a player program in c++ library, needs a timer able to pause & resume,

I found boost deadline timer is an option, but How can I restart it after stopped ?

Answer (score 3):

Your timer should wait asynchronously. In this case you can cancel a timer with [deadline_timer::cancel()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel.html), change the timer expiry time with deadline_timer::expires_from_now() and start it waiting again with [deadline_timer::async_wait()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html).

Code sample for C++03 is below:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/duration.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

/// Simple asio::deadline_timer wrapper to aggregate
/// timer, interval and handler function.
class timer
{
    typedef boost::asio::deadline_timer impl;
public:
    typedef impl::duration_type duration;
    typedef boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code, timer&)> handler_function;

    /// Create timer with specified interval and handler
    timer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, duration interval, handler_function handler)
        : impl_(io_service)
        , interval_(interval)
        , handler_(handler)
    {
    }

    /// Start asynchronous waiting
    void start()
    {
        impl_.expires_from_now(interval_);
        impl_.async_wait(boost::bind(handler_, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(*this)));
    }

    /// Stop waiting
    void stop()
    {
        impl_.cancel();
    }

private:
    impl impl_;
    duration interval_;
    handler_function handler_;
};

// Timer handler, just start next tick
void timer_tick(boost::system::error_code err, timer& t)
{
    static int tick_ = 0;
    if (!err)
    {
        std::cout << "tick " << ++tick_ << '\n';
        t.start();
    }
}

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

void timer_thread(timer& t)
{
    t.start();
    io_service.run();
}

int main()
{
    // run a timer in another thread
    timer t(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(1), timer_tick);
    boost::thread tthread(&timer_thread, boost::ref(t));

    // stop the timer after some delay
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
    t.stop();

    tthread.join();
}
```

Comment: Could do with a bit more structure and less prose. Anything you said here would be better served as a code sample, IMO

Answer (score 0):

Since the deadline timer uses [an io service object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html), you might be able to pause the timer by simply [stopping](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) the service.

Comment: no, that will stop the event loop and all processing

Comment: @juzerKicker Unless the `io_service` object is used for anything else, that will accomplish exactly what the OP wants: Pause the timer.

Comment: it's more common to use io_service for multiple operations, so if you are having one event loop for multiple pause/resumes or even using it for any other action (network i/o) your solution fails, proper way is desribed above with using timer.cancel which will in turn stop io_service processing if there are no other actions